Integration over a semiring
I'm looking into semirings.
It is known that is possible to encode derivation over a semiring by considering $d(a+b) = d(a) + d(b)$ and $d(a\cdot b) = d(a) \cdot b + d(b) \cdot a$. Both operations are commutative and everything works fine. A question I have is: is it also possible to encode integration? While $\int (a+b) \ dx = \int a \ dx + \int b \ dx$ is ok, for the product the definition is a bit more involved since it involves the integration by part formula.
However, I'm stuck and I do not know how to proceed and whether is it possible to encode integration over semirings (so preserving the commutativity of the operations). A follow-up question is: is it possible to mix integration with something else and preserve the properties of a semiring? I'm thinking about the tropical semiring, where max and sum coexist (so something like max and integration).
Hope the questio is clear. Any hint, pointer to some refences, or comment is well accepted. Thanks.

So you want to have a section of any derivation? It does not always exists and a general derivation is not always surjective. You may want to use some results to study it, e.g. the integration by part formula should hold

For example (with no smallness assumptions) $(\mathrm{Top},\coprod,\prod)$ has a differential given by $\partial$ (the boundary) it is not possible for every topological to be a boundary, one would have to be at least without boundary… You need to have non nilpotent differential at least
